# Allow user to download zip file generated on AWS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip

Here is how I do to generate ZIP and download it from a server, it works well in local development.

```
import zipfile
```

```
doc = get_object_or_404(Document,id=id_obj)
```

```
filepath = doc.file.path
filename = os.path.basename(doc.file.name)
directory = os.path.dirname(filepath)

xzip = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(directory,"%s.zip" % filename), "w")
xzip.write(filepath,filename)
xzip.close()

zip_file = open(xzip.filename, 'rb')
response = HttpResponse(zip_file, content_type='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s.zip"' % 
                                   os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
return response
```

All my static & media files are uploaded to AWS in production. So I change a little bit

```
 # filepath becomes
 filepath = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "/" + doc.file.name
```

But When I try to download it, it gives me `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`with the link:

> `https://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/media/public/files/file.pdf.zip`

the `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` is:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket_name'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media/public'
MEDIA_ROOT = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION)
```

`doc.file.path` gives me the error: `'This backend doesn't support absolute paths'`, that's why I changed to `MEDIA_ROOT + doc.file.name`

**How to do that to download from AWS the zip file generated?**

Answer (score 2):

The file exists on S3, not the local file system. When you call those `os.path.*` functions the code is trying to find the file on the local file system. It's giving you that error because that S3 URL you are giving it as the path can't be mapped to anything on the local file system.

Why don't you allow S3 to serve the file directly to the end-user's browser by simply return a redirect response with the URL of the S3 file instead of trying to read the file and return the contents in the response?

Comment: Ok I understand! can you show me how to proceed that way?

Comment: Something like `return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "/" + doc.file.name)`

Comment: Note that I am trying to create a zip file before everything. `xzip = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(directory,"%s.zip" % filename), "w")` the OP shows it. Are you talking about this? .... because the `return HttpResponseRedirect` will just generate the file

Comment: I missed the zip part. In that instance you are going to need to use the AWS SDK to copy the files from S3 to the local file system first, then zip them, then serve the zip file.

Comment: Happy that you know and try to explain, can you add an example to your answer, please!